# Из Веб-формы возвращается неверная кодировка

Tags: java, tomcat

С веб-формы после выполнения запроса, строчки на русском языке приходят в испорченном виде. В самом сервлете я напрямую задаю

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Веб страница с формой также имеет все необходимые атрибуты:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

В предобработке запроса стоит два фильтра: один на загрузку файлов, второй - на логирование, их влияние на запрос исключено, так как первый прорверяет enctype  и срабатывает только в том случае, если он multipart, второй никаких преобразований с данными объекта request не делает.

Web application использует следующее компоненты:

1. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_06-b02), Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b22, mixed mode, sharing)
2. Tomcat 6 
   -server -Xmx1024m -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

**Добавление**

Это обработчик запроса в сервлете

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {           
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    String folder = getActionName(request);
    Action action = factory.create(folder);
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = action.perform(request, response);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (url != null)
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

Далее он передает request & response в соответствующий класс, обработчик которого приведен ниже

```
public String perform(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    InputStream iS = MainServlet.context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/UserManagement/WebForm.xml");
    Properties webform = new Properties();
    try {
        webform.loadFromXML(iS);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    Integer uGID = null;
    try {

        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("GID")!=null)
            uGID = (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("GID");
        else
            uGID = 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    if (uGID==1) {
        Integer UID = null;
        Integer GID = null;
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        //Locale usual = Locale.getDefault();
        //Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru","RU"));
        String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String Login = request.getParameter("Login");
        String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
        //Locale.setDefault(usual);            
        String q = "";
        MyDB oracle = new MyDB(MyDB.Oracle);
        CallableStatement cs;
        ResultSet rs;

        try {
            if (request.getParameter("UID")!=null) {
                UID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("UID"));
            }
            if (request.getParameter("GID")!=null) {
                GID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("GID"));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        try {
            if(action.equals("remove"))
            {
                cs = oracle.conn.prepareCall("begin deleteusers(:1); end;");
                cs.setString(1,Integer.toString(UID));
                cs.execute();
            }
            else if(action.equals("adduser"))
            {
                q = "begin adduser(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5); end;";
                cs = oracle.conn.prepareCall(q);
                cs.setString(1,Login);
                cs.setString(2,Password);
                cs.setString(3,Integer.toString(GID));
                cs.setString(4,Name);
                cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
                cs.execute();
                System.out.println("Login:"+Login+" Password:"+Password+" Name:"+Name);
                if(cs.getInt(5)>0)
                {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMsg", webform.getProperty("AlreadyExists"));
                }
                else if(cs.getInt(5)==-1)
                {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMsg", webform.getProperty("Empty"));
                }

            }
            else if(action.equals("edituser"))
            {
                q = "begin ediuser (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6); end;";
                cs = oracle.conn.prepareCall(q);
                cs.setString(1,Integer.toString(UID));
                cs.setString(2,Login);
                cs.setString(3,Password);
                cs.setString(4,Name);
                cs.setString(5,Integer.toString(GID));
                cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.INTEGER);
                cs.execute();
                if(cs.getInt(6)>0)
                {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMsg", webform.getProperty("ErrorChanging"));
                }
                else if(cs.getInt(6)==-1)
                {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMsg", webform.getProperty("Empty"));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        //System.out.println(q);

        oracle.close();
    }
    else
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMsg", webform.getProperty("AccessDenied"));
    }
    return "/UserManagement.jsp";
}
```

ну и напоследок сама UserManagement.jsp

```
<div><h2><%=webform.getProperty("Adding")%></h2></div>
<form action="${urlForm}">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        <tr><td><%=webform.getProperty("Name")%></td><td><input type="text" class="text" name="Name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><%=webform.getProperty("Login")%></td><td><input type="text" class="text" name="Login"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><%=webform.getProperty("Password")%></td><td><input type="password" class="text" name="Password"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><%=webform.getProperty("Group")%></td><td>
            <select name="GID">
                <% for(Integer key: groups.keySet()){%>
                <option value="<%=key%>"><%=groups.get(key)%></option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input class="button" type="submit" value="<%=webform.getProperty("Add").trim()%>"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="adduser">
</form>
```

Comment: Попробуй в браузере посмотреть, что за кодировку он выставил.

Comment: Вот попробовал сделать как у вас.. у меня системная кодировка UTF-8, поэтому я для чистоты эксперимента наоборот везде сделал windows-1251.. и никаких дефектов. Выбрал UTF-8 везде.. везде UTF-8 и работает..

Comment: Вот по поводу multipart поподробнее.. чем вы разбираете multipart-данные? Или ваша форма не использует всё-таки multipart?

Comment: 2 cy6erGn0m
Форма не использует multipart. - Это к тому что фильтр никак не влияет на параметры запроса.

2 evm
В браузере стоит UTF-8

Comment: Ну тогда это чудеса какие-то. Код в студию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вашей формы не указан метод. Стало быть, у вас GET? Передавать пароли через GET - очень плохо, используйте POST. Возможно и проблема с кодировкой уйдёт сама собой.

И ещё: использование Java-кода в JSP - старый и очень дурной тон. Используйте EL-expressions и JSTL . Сравните, например, цикл:

```
<c:forEach var="e" values="${groups}">
  <option value="${e.key}">${e.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

UPD: если бы потребовался обязательно GET, то можно было бы попытаться добавить аттрибут accept-charset к тегу form.

Comment: Так это как-то повлияло? Помогло или никакого эффекта?

Comment: Да, дело действительно было в атрибуте method.

Comment: Закройте вопрос и пометьте ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел в неотвеченных.

Comment: Не нашел как закрыть

Comment: Под оценкой ответа есть рука вниз, а под ней - галка - верный ответ. После этого, можно закрыть.. внизу вопроса есть ссылки править | закрыть | тревога. Жмёте закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дан, тем не менее недавно напоролся, поделюсь - фаерфокс иногда корежит кодировку через GET - в частности, если не указана кодировка *принимающей* страницы, передается байт-код cp1251. Имейте в виду на будущее

```
<? echo !empty($_GET['t'])?$_GET['t']:''; // мне выдало ромбики:) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте кодировку файлов.

Comment: Кодировка файлов в конечном итоге ни на что не влияет.